# Knockout different radio button list per row

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a list of People. For each person I have a true/false status. I want this to bind per person. If you check the below Fiddle, it is binding correctly but my radio buttons are not working as wanted. I would like each row to have it's own set of radio buttons (different name for each row).

For example. Row 1 click to true, Row 2 click to false. That should be allowed but the names are conflicting therefor removing row one's selection. Thank you

http://jsfiddle.net/ef3fV/5/

```
<table width="300px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="Status" value="true" data-bind="checked: Status" />
                <input type="radio" name="Status" value="false" data-bind="checked: Status" />
            </td>
            <td><button data-bind="click: $root.changeStatus">Change Status</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

​

```
function People(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name= data.Name;
    self.Status = ko.observable(data.Status);
}

function PeopleViewModel(userId) {
    var self = this;

    self.people = ko.observable([
                            { Name: 'Bert', Status: true },
                            { Name: 'Charles', Status: true },
                            { Name: 'Denise', Status: false }
                        ]);
    self.changeStatus = function()
    {
        alert("Change " + this.Name + " to " + this.Status);
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new PeopleViewModel());
```

​

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things:

- The `name` attribute is the same across all people. You can change this using the `attr` binding and prefixing each radio button group with the person's name.
- You probably meant to make `people` an `observableArray` and not just an `observable`.
- Each person's `Status` property should be observable as well, if you want the underlying data model to update.
- The `value` that you assign `Status` to should be a string.

Here's the modified code with the updates:

**HTML:**

```
<table width="300px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" value="true" data-bind="attr: { name: Name + '-status' }, checked: Status" />
                <input type="radio" value="false" data-bind="attr: { name: Name + '-status' }, checked: Status" />
            </td>
            <td><button data-bind="click: $root.changeStatus">Change Status</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**​

```
function People(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = data.Name;
    self.Status = ko.observable(data.Status);
}

function PeopleViewModel(userId) {
    var self = this;

    self.people = ko.observableArray([
    {
        Name: 'Bert',
        Status: ko.observable('true')
    },
    {
        Name: 'Charles',
        Status: ko.observable('true')
    },
    {
        Name: 'Denise',
        Status: ko.observable('false')
    }]);

    self.changeStatus = function() {
        alert("Change " + this.Name + " to " + this.Status());
        if (this.Status() === "true") {
            this.Status('false');
        } else {
            this.Status('true');
        }
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new PeopleViewModel());​
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/AKKvz/

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was just trying to get a workable demo. The attr binding was what I needed.